# Vanishing \footcite if the titlesec package is loaded

Tags: footnotes, citing, titlesec, footmisc

I'm trying to use multiple `\footcite` citations at the end of a `\section`. This works as expected as long as I don't have the `titlesec` package loaded, but as soon as I do, all but the last `\footcite` in the `\section` vanish: In the printed heading, there appears a footnote marker, but there is no corresponding footnote at the end of the page.

Here's an example, hopefully making clear what I mean:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 4in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@article{A, author = {Alpha, Amber}, title = {Title}}
@article{B, author = {Beta, Bryan}, title = {Title2}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[bottom,multiple]{footmisc}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Heading%
\footcite{A}\footcite{B}
}

\section{Section Heading%
\footcite{A}\footcite{B}
}

Text%
\footcite{A}\footcite{B}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following PDF; notice how footnote 3 is missing at the bottom:
[image: result_flawed]

However, if I comment out the line `\usepackage{titlesec}`, I get the desired result:
[image: result_desired]

The `\footcite`s in the `\chapter` and in the text are only included to show that for some reason, the effect does not appear there.

How can I solve this problem (except for avoiding `titlesec`)?

I'd also be curious to learn why this happens in the first place, but please consider this only a "bonus question" of sorts; my primary concern is a practical solution of the prblem.

This happens both with pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTex with TeX Live 2013, in the way it comes with Ubuntu 14.04, except that I manually updated the `titlesec` package to the newest version in CTAN.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It's a known problem and the link shows a workaround for normal footnotes, which should be similar for `\footcite`, by using `\footcitetext` instead of `\footnotetext`.